# Converting InstallShield script to another installer

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

What I mean is that I have .iss script that would be converted into installation script for say InnoSetup or smth that produces MSI package.

Is there anything like that? I googled and googled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of any tool that can convert directly the .iss file, but you have the option to build the .iss file in InstallShield, then get the [output EXE and convert it into an MSI](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=convert%20EXE%20to%20msi&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest).

Comment: Agreed; the .iss file is just a serialization of responses to the wizard dialogs. It doesn't contain any of the logic of the installer.